# react-native SQLite-storage INSERT statement

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite

I use `react-native` `react-native-sqlite-storage` in my project and I am struggling to insert data

I managed to successfully read the pre populated table I created in

> ./android/app/src/main/assets/Mydb.db
> but the INSERT statement somehow does not work.

simplified sample code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

let db;

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    // SQLite connection / config settings
    db = SQLite.openDatabase({  name: 'testTable', //Name of my table
    createFromLocation: "~MyDB.db", // Name of my DB
  });  
}

selectExample = () => {     // working
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM testTable', [], (tx, results) => {
            console.log("Query completed");

            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let row = results.rows.item(i);
                console.log(`My AWG: ${row.AWG}, My Metric: ${row.metric}`);
            }
        });
    });
  }

  updateDatabase = () => {  // not working
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql('Insert into testTable (AWG, metric) VALUES (?,?)',
            [28,0.5],
            (tx,results) => {
            console.log("Results", results.rowsAffected);
            },(err) => {
            console.error(err);
            }
        )
      })
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.selectExample(); // working
    this.updateDatabase(); // issue
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} onPress={() => this.onPress() } />
        </View>
    );
  }
```

in the console I get  `Results 1` as feedback, so the query seems fine but when I open `MyDB.db` with the mac app: `DB Browser for SQLite`, no changes happened no new rows..

Am I missing something here?

Comment: as i am trying to debug it, i found out that my script is successfully inserting data into a database, but it is obviously not the db i configured in the "createFromLocation" Parameter... and i haven't found the correct db file yet...what the heck? :)

Comment: in fact the rows are not stored in the configured file in './android/app/src/main/assets' i can even delete this file, and still insert into the db, and also read from it! obviously a other file is used, but i damn can't find it anywhere . i don't get it